# JPA findDistinctPropertyBy magic method doesn't work as expected when using spring-boot-starter-jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

So, here is the problem that I got.

I am building a database model structure by JPA which has a many to many relation, here is the class model

```
public class UserActivityRelation{
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id",nullable = false)
    private User participant;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "activity_id",nullable = false)
    private Activity activity;
}
```

here is the corresponding DAO code that I followed the spring-doc [spring-boot-jpa](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.8.0.RELEASE/reference/html/)

```
public List<UserActivityRelation> findDistinctParticipantByParticipantAndActivity(User user, Activity activity);
```

hoping to distinct rows with same `user_id`, but it came with an unexpected result, the sql sentence is as follows:

```
select distinct useractivi0_.id as id1_1_, useractivi0_.created_time 
as created_2_1_, useractivi0_.modified_time as modified3_1_,
useractivi0_.activity_id as activity5_1_, useractivi0_.user_id as
user_id6_1_, useractivi0_.status as status4_1_ from act_users 
useractivi0_ left outer join users user1_ on useractivi0_.user_id=user1_.id 
left outer join activities activity2_ on 
useractivi0_.activity_id=activity2_.id where (user1_.id is null) 
and (activity2_.id is null)
```

the sql code seems really complex, but the point is clear, findDistinct only has effect on the primary key `id` rather than the `participant`----`user_id`, and it uses a lot of left outer join...

At first I thought I write the method wrong, so I test it with another method name

`findDistinctHEHEByParticipantAndActivity` , as you can see it has `HEHE` in the middle which has nothing do to with model class, neither a property nor a method... and it just gave an identical sql sentence, which I was so confused to see...

So, is it just the way that JPA with hibernate works or did I do it wrong?

Comment: It is the way query creation works in Spring Data JPA. It selects the distinct  `UserActivityRelation` and that is done based on the id. There is no such thing as a select `distinct<property>`. The <property> is simply ignored until the `By` part.

Comment: M. Deinum if so, findDistinct doesn't make any sense. id is the unique identifier for each row in the database, I configure it as auto-increment , no need to use distinct at all then. Besides, while without distinct, the sql code has not so many outer left join parts, only a where clause at the end. How come it generate  these useless join clause when using distinct?

Comment: The distinct can be useful depending on the query method you write it could be that the generated query returns the same row multiple times and you want it to limit it. Why it generates the query it does I have no idea I guess something similar would be created if you would use play criteria API and do a distinct as well.

Comment: Ok.. I see. Maybe I should just use the jpa criteria api instead of findBy methods, although a little handful.. Is that play criteria API you said the apis from play framework ?

Comment: No that was a typo which should have been plain criteria API. So the basic JPA Criteria API.